# Remove specific text from a paragraph Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

In the code below there are check-boxes and every time a check box is checked it add that check-box value (works). But when it is unchecked it should remove that check-box value. But instead it is just adding the value twice. How do I add and remove that value that is unchecked?

**Here is the code sample**

```
//Looks for every checkbox
        $('#index '+ selected +' #cbFieldSet .icheck').each( function(i, name){
            console.log("#"+ $(name).attr("id"));
            if($('input[name='+$(name).attr('name')+']').attr('checked', false)){
            //checks what checkbox has been check. Gets that checkbox id
            $('#index '+ selected +' #cbFieldSet #'+ $(name).attr("id")).click( function(){
                // $("#cb-"+playerStart).click(function(){

                //console.log(i);
                console.log('yes');

                //add to popup box paragragh
                $('#popupDialog #info').append($(name).val());

        });

        }else if($('input[name='+$(name).attr('name')+']').attr('checked', true)){
            //checks what checkbox has been check. Gets that checkbox id
            $('#index '+ selected +' #cbFieldSet #'+ $(name).attr("id")).change( function(){
                // $("#cb-"+playerStart).click(function(){

                //console.log(i);
                console.log('yes');

                //add to popup box paragragh
                $('#popupDialog #info').remove( ":contains("+ $(name).val() +")" );

            });
        }

        });
```

Comment: That's not the whole of the relevant jQuery, is it? Because you seem to have omitted where `name` is defined. If this is an excerpt from a function, post enough information that it makes sense; think [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of jquery is used, you might want .prop() rather than .attr(). 
Only versions pre-1.6 have attr("checked",true/false) i.e. as boolean.
.prop( "checked" ) should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

This code is not easy to read, partly because you have copy-pasted the same comments in both the "checked" and "unchecked" cases.  You've also left out some context-- the indentation is off, and I don't know what `selected` is.

Anyway-- in addition to what user3785863 has said above, the form of .attr() you're using *sets* attribute values, when you want to *read* the existing value.

In other words, `$('input(...)').attr('checked', false)` does not test whether the checkbox is checked; it *sets* its value to boolean `false`, and then returns the checkbox itself, which means your first `if` statement will always run, and the second one never will.

So, I think what you actually mean is `if ($(...).attr("checked") == "false")`.

(I think you also have true and false the wrong way round, plus some other issues, but this might get you unstuck...)